# webflux with reactor does not print exception in bodyToMono

Tags: spring-webflux

I expect either map or doOnError prints the log, but the fact is neither of them does so, making it seem like both fail to run. If `bodyToMono` throws exception, how to print it?

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> tryWebflux(ServerRequest request) {
        log.info("start controller");

        Mono bodyMono = request.bodyToMono(HashMap.class)
                .doOnError(e -> log.error("something wrong", e))
                .map(body -> {
                    log.info("in map");
                    return body;
                });
        bodyMono.log().subscribe(System.out::println);
        return ServerResponse.ok().build();
}
```

Result:

```
  [reactor-http-nio-2] reactor.util.Loggers$Slf4JLogger: onSubscribe(FluxMap.MapSubscriber)
  [reactor-http-nio-2] reactor.util.Loggers$Slf4JLogger: request(unbounded)
  [reactor-http-nio-2] reactor.util.Loggers$Slf4JLogger: onComplete()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my guess it is because of this line here:

```
bodyMono.log().subscribe(System.out::println);
```

You see in most cases you never subscribe in your application. The one that subscribes is the one whom initiated the call, and in most cases this is the calling client (front end, caller to the api, etc. etc.) Your server is the publisher, and in this server you want to build an event chain that basically does things one after the other.

By subscribing in the middle you are breaking the event chain.

Try:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> tryWebflux(ServerRequest request) {
    return request.bodyToMono(HashMap.class)
            .doOnError(e -> log.error("something wrong", e))
            .map(body -> {
                log.info("in map");
                return body;
            }).log() // We log, chaining on as you did before
            .then(ServerResponse.ok().build()); 
            // Here we use the then() keyword to still keep chaining on the mono
}
```

It is very important to never break the event chain. If you see yourself subscribing in the middle, you have probably done something wrong, unless your application is the initiator of something, or the "consumer".

Comment: bodyMono.log is added to see logs. It was not there at first. I want to check `doOnError` or `map` is executed.

Comment: well you should never subscribe in the middle of your application.

Comment: What I mean is even without this  `bodyMono.log().subscribe(System.out::println);`, the log is still not printed, like the statements not run

Comment: and when you debug you application? you have posted too little, the respons looks like?, who is calling this code?